How to set up deb question priority with an apt flag?
We have the nice tool dpkg-reconfigure to re-ask install configuration questions of a single package. For example, by dpkg-reconfigure -plow something I can re-configure the package something, i.e. re-run its installation script.
We also have the apt tool to download a package from a repository, along with its recursive dependency structure, and install and configure them, in the correct order. Thus, for example, an apt install something installs "something" to my system, with all of its dependencies, and everything will be downloaded (if needed) and installed, in the correct order, as needed.
I want to combine them both.
I want to install a package with apt, while all the questions are asked from me.
Can I do it something, with a - maybe tricky - apt flag, or configuration change?

The fun thing is that googling results an unthinkable amount of setting up the priorities of various different repos. I found nothing about setting the prio of the install questions, except some about dpkg-reconfigure.

You can set the debconf priority by setting the DEBIAN_PRIORITY environment variable:
DEBIAN_PRIORITY=low apt install foo

